# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object, ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, async-await, signalr

I am writing an API using SignalR in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I am totally new to .NET Core, and am pretty new to SignalR too. I am having an issue executing MongoDB (Atlas) queries which are running in transactions. It appears that the transaction sessions are expiring before the queries are executing. I'm quite sure it's a `async`/`await` issue, but don't seem to be able to fix it.

My Hub method looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateProfile(object profileDto)
{
  try
  {
    ProfileDTO profile = ((JsonElement) profileDto).ToObject<ProfileDTO>();
    _profile.UpdateProfile(profile);
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the `_profile.UpdateProfile()` method looks like this:

```
public void UpdateProfile(ProfileDTO profileDto)
{
  _databaseService.ExecuteInTransaction(async session =>
  {
    var profile = _mapper.Map<ProfileModel>(profileDto);
    var existingUser = (await _userCollectionService
        .FindAsync(session, user => user.Profille.Sub == profileDto.sub)
      ).FirstOrDefault();

    if (existingUser == null)
    {
      var newUser = new UserModel();
      newUser.Profille = profile;
      await _userCollectionService.CreateAsync(session, newUser);
    }
    else
    {
      existingUser.Profille = profile;
      // the error occurs on the following line
      await _userCollectionService.UpdateAsync(session, existingUser.Id, existingUser);
    }
  });
}
```

My `ExecuteInTransaction()` method is an attempt to generalise the transaction/session process, and looks like this:

```
public async void ExecuteInTransaction(DatabaseAction databaseAction)
{
  using (var session = await Client.StartSessionAsync())
  {
    try
    {
      session.StartTransaction();
      databaseAction(session);
      await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

I have indicated the line in the `UpdateProfile()` where the error occurs. The full error looks like this:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.CoreSessionHandle'.
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WrappingCoreSession.ThrowIfDisposed()
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WrappingCoreSession.get_IsInTransaction()
> at MongoDB.Driver.ClientSessionHandle.get_IsInTransaction()
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateBulkWriteOperation(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.ReplaceOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1 filter, TDocument replacement, ReplaceOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync) at IndistinctChatter.API.Services.Business.Profile.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<UpdateProfile>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /Volumes/Data/Users/marknorgate/Documents/Development/source/indistinct-chatter/api-dotnet/Services/Business/Profile.cs:line 48 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object state) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext executionContext, Action`1 callback, TState& state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

So it seems the `session` object is expiring before the `await _userCollectionService.UpdateAsync(session, existingUser.Id, existingUser);` line is executing. The line `await session.CommitTransactionAsync();` is executing first.

Where am I going wrong? I feel a `Task` coming on...

Comment: Change `ExecuteInTransaction` to be `async Task` and await it in your Hub method. Hint: Avoid `async void` whenever possible.

Side-note, try to avoid `object` in your Hub methods, you should be able to about the ugly `((JsonElement) profileDto).ToObject<ProfileDTO>();` code by just accepting `ProfileDTO` in the Hub method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DatabaseAction` is not an asynchronous delegate. It seems to be `Action<T>` but what you really need is `Func<T, Task>`. So when you do `async session =>` that code gets turned into an `async void` signature. Due to it being `void`, you cannot `await` it. This leads to your `async` code being scheduled to a threadpool thread and the call immediately returns. This has the knock on effect that `await session.CommitTransactionAsync()` commits while potentially, your delegate hasn't even started running yet. Your code inside `ExecuteInTransaction` is now considered "done" and exits, disposing your `session` along the way due to `using` block.

To fix this, you need to change your `DatabaseAction`'s signature and then `await databaseAction(session);`

Comment: That sounds marvellous, but I'm not sure what code changes I need to make. How do I change the `DatabaseAction`'s signature, and what to? I may have to ask you to kindly spoon-feed me the code since a lot of what you're telling me is alien. `Func<T, Task>` for example! Please help!

Comment: Incidentally, my `DatabaseAction` delegate looks like this: `public delegate void DatabaseAction(IClientSessionHandle session, AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent);`

Comment: I worked it out! I changed my `DatabaseAction` signature to `public delegate Task DatabaseAction(IClientSessionHandle sessiont);` and then just `await`ed `databaseAction(session)`. Thanks for your help! But I would like to know about `Func<t, Task>`. I am studying lots of Pluralsight at the moment, and I'm sure that will come up in the C# courses.

Comment: `Func<T, Task>` is a built-in delegate that is basically exactly your manually created delegate. So instead of using `DatabaseAction`, your method can just accept `Func<IClientSessionHandle, Task>`

Comment: Yeah, I worked that out in the last ten minutes. Thanks, @JohanP!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a work around, although I am not entirely happy with the solution.

I discovered the `AutoResetEvent()`, so modified my code like this:

```
public async void ExecuteInTransaction(DatabaseAction databaseAction)
{
  AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  using var session = await Client.StartSessionAsync();

  try
  {
    session.StartTransaction();
    databaseAction(session, autoResetEvent);
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

and

```
public void UpdateProfile(ProfileDTO profileDto)
{
  _databaseService.ExecuteInTransaction(async (session, autoResetEvent) =>
  {
    var profile = _mapper.Map<ProfileModel>(profileDto);
    var existingUser = (await _userCollectionService
        .FindAsync(session, user => user.Profille.Sub == profileDto.sub)
      ).FirstOrDefault();

    if (existingUser == null)
    {
      var newUser = new UserModel();
      newUser.Profille = profile;
      await _userCollectionService.CreateAsync(session, newUser);
    }
    else
    {
      existingUser.Profille = profile;
      await _userCollectionService.UpdateAsync(session, existingUser.Id, existingUser);
    }

    autoResetEvent.Set();
  });
}
```

Seems to work, but it is an extra step at the end of each database operation that I need to remember. If anyone can improve on this I would be pleased to hear about it!